# Legacy/obsolete UK postcodes

Tags: data-request, geospatial, postal-code, uk

I don't expect anyone to be able to answer this, but hope to be proved wrong.  Does anyone know if there is a reasonably comprehensive source of old postcode data?  I have data going back a few years and a fair proportion are codes that appear to have been been retired by Royal Mail.  Has anyone has found decent source of such codes?

Comment: It would be easier if you add the year you want to find postcodes before or after of it. You said you have data going back a few years. But how many years before? :)

Comment: Well my data goes back nearly 10 years, but it would certainly be useful to know how people have tackled this more generally :)

Comment: It would be really useful to me to know a ballpark figure of how many obsolete postcodes there are to help me know how to tackle a problem I have. 10k? 100k? Going back 10 years would be enough!

Comment: Found the answer to my own question: about 800,000.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This site [UK Data Service](http://borders.edina.ac.uk/html/pcluts_main.html) has historical postcodes from 1988. But I don't know if it is open data since I have to login. I hope this will help you :)

Comment: The link is no longer working. I tried looking for a new one in the UK Data Service site but couldn't find anything

Answer (score 5):

Postcode data is now available on the [ONS website](https://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/search?collection=Dataset&sort=-created&tags=all(PRD_ONSPD)).

From that page you can download a CSV file which when uncompressed is over one gigabyte in size. One of the fields is `DOTERM`, which gives you the date of termination. It therefore should be a comprehensive source of data on retired postcodes.

Further info on which ONS postcode product to use [here](https://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/documents/a-guide-to-ons-geography-postcode-products-1).